# The right way to Set Envirement Variables in c# to securly push it to Git

Tags: c#, git, environment-variables

I am new to this  secure push to `Git`.

I did a research and I found that someother languages use Envirenement variables to securely hide sensative data while pushing the project to `Git`.

So here is my test app and how I defined my varible envirenements in my Console App :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConverInput input = new ConverInput();
    Calculate calc = new Calculate();\
    try
    {
        double firstNumber = input.ConvertValueToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        double SecondNumber = input.ConvertValueToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        string operation = Console.ReadLine();
        double result = calc.Calculation(firstNumber, SecondNumber, operation);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Test of securing data push to git using variable envirenement
        string variableConfidentiel = "Here my password";
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("var1", variableConfidentiel, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        String var = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("var1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        MessageBox.Show(var);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now, It seems working but **I dont know if it is the right way to do it** . Secondly, I **dont know where should I declare my**  `System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` so I could be able later to use `.gitignore` on that file.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried user secret available in visual studio

Comment: Thank you Sir Ididn't know something Like user secret exists.. I will take a look at it.